# Mahout: Missing class to create Sequence Files

Tags: java, hadoop, mahout, mahout-recommender, sequencefile

I'm following the instructions at [the mahout site](http://mahout.apache.org/users/basics/creating-vectors-from-text.html) for converting an existing file to a sequence file:

```
VectorWriter vectorWriter = SequenceFile.createWriter(filesystem,
                                                  configuration,
                                                  outfile,
                                                  LongWritable.class,
                                                  SparseVector.class);

long numDocs = vectorWriter.write(new VectorIterable(), Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

I've included the mahout jar in my maven project:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
        <artifactId>mahout-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

But it won't write the file.

I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.SerializationFactory.getSerializer(SerializationFactory.java:73)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.init(SequenceFile.java:963)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$RecordCompressWriter.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1136)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.createWriter(SequenceFile.java:397)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.createWriter(SequenceFile.java:284)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.createWriter(SequenceFile.java:265)
```

which, after further investigation, is caused by:

```
Serilization class not found: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization
```

That suggests to me that I'm missing a jar-- does anyone know which one?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using it within Lenskit, and the `Configuration` class tries to use `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` which (for whatever reason) doesn't have the mahout or hadoop packages. The complete code is:

```
final Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.setClassLoader(Configuration.class.getClassLoader());

final Path path = new Path(POINTS_PATH + "/pointsFile");

LocalFileSystem fs = new LocalFileSystem();
fs.initialize(URI.create(POINTS_PATH + "/pointsFile"), configuration);

final SequenceFile.Writer writer =
        SequenceFile.createWriter(
                fs,
                configuration,
                path,
                Text.class,
                VectorWritable.class);
```